# Access SQL Server Data with F#

Tags: f#

I would like to access SQL server with F#

It doesn't seem like there is any way to generate models using the Entity Framework. I have seen some answers on S.O. but they appear to be quite generic. I would ideally like to select or update using strongly typed objects.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [FSharp.Data.SqlClient](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/). SqlCommandProvider allows you to write strongly-typed selects/updates.